# jquery function to convert datetime, split date time "2010-10-18 10:06" to return "18/10/2010" and "10:06"

Tags: jquery, datetime

Hi I was wondering if there is any jquery function around which can take this dateTime "2010-10-18 10:06" and convert and split it returning "2010/10/18" and "10:06".

It would be also nice if the same function could either receive "2010-10-18 10:06" or "2010-10-18" only and return as mentioned above, or different formats besides "2010/10/18" like 18-10-2010" or and 18th of October 2010, giving the option but not that important, just curious about jQuery power dealing with dates.

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the first part of this question is particularly a JQuery issue - just general Javascript. Are you input values strings or date objects?

Comment: They come from database, but I thinks they are treated as string.

Comment: So my example will do the trick just nicely!

Comment: Well then, there are two question in one here. The first question asks how to split a datetime, expressed as a string, into the date and time parts. This can easily be acheived using the javascript string 'split' function, using a space as the separator. This results in a two element array, with the first element containg the date and the second containing the time. The second part of the question asks how to 'do the same' with a date time, or just a date - I'm not sure what the OP would expect the time part to contain is the case of just a date being supplied?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Converting with **[DateJs](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/)** should be as easy as:

```
var d1 = Date.parse('2010-10-18, 10:06 AM');
alert(d1.toString('dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT'));
```

It's currently the best library around

Comment: it says invalid procedure :-(, i copied your example

Comment: Sorry I did not downloaded the datejs.

Comment: For one small operation, using entire file is not good I think.. Look at below answer by Henry, we can split date and time in to two parts... correct me if I am in wrong direction..

Answer (score 16):

Without a any external jQuery plugin like DateJs. We can get the date as given below.

```
var datetime= '2010-10-18 10:06 AM' // Default datetime will be like this.

//By Spliting the input control value with space
var date=datetime.split(' ')[0];
//date -2010-10-18
```

Comment: Really nice idea Henry, sometime we unknowingly do 1+1 in   "1 - 1 + 1 + 1" way..

Comment: Yes this is definitely appropriate for this.
Of course use [1] to get the time instead of date :)

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" id="tbDateTime" value="2010-10-18 10:06" />
<input type="text" id="tbDate" value="" />
<input type="text" id="tbTime" value="" />

<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            var dateTimeSplit = $('#tbDateTime').val().split(' ');

            var dateSplit = dateTimeSplit[0].split('-');
            var currentDate = dateSplit[2] + '/' + dateSplit[1] + '/' + dateSplit[0];
            //currentDate is 18/10/2010

            $('#tbDate').val(currentDate);

            var currentTime = dateTimeSplit[1];
            //currentTime is 10:06

            $('#tbTime').val(currentTime);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[datejs](http://www.datejs.com/). Check it, its cool and it does pretty good job for all the possibilities and error handling is also pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [Here](http://github.com/vitch/jquery-methods/raw/master/date.js)

It includes a function called fromString which would help you.