# How do I convert DateTime format to ShortDateString in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a date that I would like to convert to String format.  /Date(1281067200000)/ is supposed to be 08/06/2010 12:00:00:00.  How do I convert /Date(1281067200000)/ to 8/6/2010?

Comment: If you are following the MVC paradigm then the controller should provide the data to your view in the format needed. The view should be 'dumb'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATED]**
Use [dateJS](http://www.datejs.com/):

[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402386/jquery-function-to-convert-datetime-split-date-time-2010-10-18-1006-to-retur)

**Edit:**
Try this: http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm

Comment: This is what I am running into, but the "/Date()/" is messing up my conversion :(

Comment: I did some testing... var formatDate = new Date(1281067200000) is what I am looking for. Is there a way to use this "/Date(1281067200000)/" and add to make the conversion

Comment: You can remove unnecessary substrings:

var formatDate = new Date("/Date(1281067200000)/".replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""))

Comment: I used a substring command then convert to number. Thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What type of string format? You could use `yourDate.toString()` or `yourDate.toLocaleDateString()` depending on your use case.

Comment: My date returns /Date(1281067200000)/ when I would like to have something like 7/30/2010